# for-loop to foreach with negative(i--) statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, foreach, logic

If I have list of data, I want delete separate rows (not bulk delete) with a loop.

Here my Code

```
var objecctCount = listItemsDelete.Count;
for (int i = objecctCount; i > 0; i--)
{
    listItemsDelete[i].DeleteObject();
    spDataContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

where,

- `listItemsDelete` is list of data,
- `listItemsDelete[i].DeleteObject();` delete separate row from `listItemsDelete`,
- `spDataContext.ExecuteQuery();` is helps update values to the `listItemsDelete`

My logic is working good.
my question is, Is it possible to change the for-loop to foreach with negative `statement`? Because my knowledge about foreach is helps to work with positive statement(I++).

Comment: Can you convert my code to foreach code?

Comment: Does `listItemsDelete[i].DeleteObject();` remove it from listItemsDelete? Because if you use `foreach` then you can't alter the collection you are looping through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to reverse the loop?

```
foreach(var obj in listItemsDelete.Reverse())
{
    obj.DeleteObject();
    spDataContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Since you are using .NET 2 you can't use LINQ. Stay with your for-loop but fix following error.

Instead of

```
for (int i = objecctCount; i > 0; i--)
// ...
```

use this:

```
for (int i = objecctCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
// ...
```

Comment: But i can't Call the `Reverse()` function

Comment: Add `using System.Linq` to the top of your code file. [`Enumerable.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358497(v=vs.100).aspx) is a LINQ extension method. What is `listItemsDelete` at all?

Comment: Am using asp.net 2.0. Is it okay?

Comment: Also saying specify method does not support

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper: LINQ is new in .net 3.5. You should use your for-loop. But fix the error, use `for(int i = objecctCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)` instead.

Comment: Yes, Your last comment was worked, Just I changed it. thanks